# Looking for Q_WS_X11 - not found

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

Trying to build code for ADTF using cmake and I get the following error. Could anyone let me know what is missing from my end? OS is Windows

```
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11 - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - found
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found
-- Found OpenGL: opengl32
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find Qt4 (missing: QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE QT_RCC_EXECUTABLE
  QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE) (found version "4.7.1")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1328 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:76 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/ViL_ADTF_filter/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/ViL_ADTF_filter/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: The message "Looking for Q_WS_X11 - not found" is not the **error**. The actual error is "Could NOT find Qt4". As you could guess, the error is about not finding QT4 library. Exactly this error prevents from building the project.

Comment: SO what do you suggest . I have added QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE to the env variables. I have edited the path inside qt.config . Provided the path of qmake.exe in the PATH variable as well

Comment: According to the error message, CMake has found **part** of QT4, this fact corresponds to message `found version "4.7.1"`. But CMake hasn't found utils corresponding to missed variables. Variable `QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE` denotes executable named `moc-qt4`, `moc4` or `moc`, variable `QT_RCC_EXECUTABLE` denotes executable named `rcc`, variable `QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE` denotes executable named `uic-qt4`, `uic4` or `uic`. Do you have any of these executables in your QT installation?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the quick response. I have moc.exe, uic.exe and rcc.exe inside the bin folder. i.e. here C:\Program Files\Qt\4.7.1\qt-4.7.1_win64_vc100\bin. I have added C:\Program Files\Qt\4.7.1\qt-4.7.1_win64_vc100  inside the qt.config file and as PATH variable  C:\Program Files\Qt\4.7.1\qt-4.7.1_win64_vc100\bin

Comment: Hm, according to the code, `PATH` is not used for search these executables. What is output of command `qmake -query QT_INSTALL_BINS`? Exactly this output is used as a directory for search aforementioned executables.

Comment: C:DKt_471/bin is the response in cmd . So should I be adding this in qt.config . Also i changed the existing C:/SDK/Qt_471  path written in the qt.config to C:\Program Files\Qt\4.7.1\qt-4.7.1_win64_vc100\ earlier. Should I be keeping C:DKt_471/bin there as well

Answer (score 0):

Just provided the path of all the missing executables in the CMakeLists and it worked. Thanks for all the responses